# How to limit query results with Django Rest filters

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I am working on an api built with `Django Rest Framework`. I have defined several `model` classes and I have also created some filters to apply on certain queries that happen in the specified `api-endpoints`.

I am trying to apply LIMIT in the `queryset` but I would prefer to not 
use the Django notation e.x. `Entry.objects.all()[:5]`. Instead I would like to be able to apply the limit from inside the filter associated with the model.

Until now I haven't find any solution. I am thinking that I should find a way to define a filter with default value something that would result in not limiting the queryset and if a request reaches the endpoint and contains something like `?filter=10` then the queryset should be limited to the first 10.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use Django Rest Framework pagination. The pagination_class `LimitOffsetPagination` give you the ability to limit the number of returned entries in a query_param.

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/

Comment: That is very close to what I need indeed! Though in that case I would like to override the `LimitOffsetPagination` class and give to the parameter `offset` a default value (probably 0) so that the user will only have to specify the `limit` parameter. 
I am thinking of using the `PageNumberPagination` and override the `page_size_query_param` parameter to have a default value `limit`. Does that sound reasonable?

Comment: Yes, this is the good solution. As stated in the documentation, the param ``page_size_query_param`` can be used to allow the client control the request page size. In the ``PageNumberPagination`` this param is set as default to None.

Comment: That might sound silly, but I can't figure out where to place the custom pagination class.

Comment: You have two choices. You can specify the default Pagination class in your settings ``DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS`` in the ``REST_FRAMEWORK`` settings dict. Per view by using the class attribute pagination_class and specify your subclass.

Comment: But where should I place the pagination class code? (I am referring to the first choice)

Comment: With the first choice you need to specify the value in the settings.py of your project.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94210/discussion-between-pgryllos-and-guillaume-pannatier).

Answer (score 5):

In `ListApiView` Overwrite `finalize_response` function. I did not find any other inbuilt method or parameter to set limit on response data.

```
from rest_framework.generics import ListAPIView

class BoolQSearch(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Model1.objects.all()
    serializer_class = Model1Serializer

    def finalize_response(self, request, response, *args, **kwargs):
        response.data = response.data[:5]
        return super().finalize_response(request, response, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks ! Great solution when you don't want to use pagination (for an autocomplete endpoint for example). I added `if response.status_code == 200:` to avoid errors (in my case a filter was required with django-filters)

Answer (score 3):

You can extend or customize pagination classes available in [drf](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/)

```
  class UserSpecificPagination(LimitOffsetPagination):
      def get_limit(self, request):
          if logic_met(request.user):
            self.max_limit = custom_limit
      return super(UserSpecificPagination, self).get_limit(request)
```

set the class as `pagination_class` in `ListAPIView` or DRF settings

Answer (score 1):

you should use the pagination api from django-rest

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/

look at the `limit` option