# Django REST, How to display every 5 element in a response?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Now the serializer displays all the data from the CoinCosts model in response (price,timestamp), but only every 5 element is needed, how to do it? Thanks

I need something like Entry.objects.all()[::5], but I don’t know how to do this with my code.

My code now:

serializers.py

```
class CoinCostsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    fields = ('price', 'timestamp')
    model = CoinCosts

class CoinSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('symbol', 'crr', 'costs')
        model = Coins
    costs = CoinCostsSerializer(source='filtered_coincosts', many=True)
```

views.py

```
class DateTimeGteFilter(filters.IsoDateTimeFilter):
    def filter(self, qs, value):
        if value != None:
            return qs.prefetch_related(Prefetch('coincosts_set', to_attr='filtered_coincosts', queryset=CoinCosts.objects.filter(timestamp__gte=value)
                )
            )
        else:
            return qs

class CoinCostFilterSet(filters.FilterSet):
    timestamp = DateTimeGteFilter()

    class Meta:
        model = Coins
        fields = {
            'symbol': ['exact'],
        }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to limit query results with Django Rest filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33503909/how-to-limit-query-results-with-django-rest-filters)

Comment: This is not that. They talk about limits. And I need to display every fifth entry. Without limiting the total number.

Comment: For Example. Now records with id are displayed: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 ... But they should  id: 1,5,10.... Maybe i need use  [::2]. But how?

Comment: Does returning the queryset from filter work for you? `return qs[::5]`? You can always log the list before you return from filter to see if it's consistent. Maybe get in both `if` and `else` the result and slice it, convert into a list if needed.

Comment: return qs not work, Got AttributeError . Because i have in serializator 'costs = CoinCostsSerializer(source='filtered_coincosts', many=True)'

Answer (score 0):

You can use **try** and **except** like this in views.py in your def:

```
try:
    obj = Entry.objects.all()[::5]
except IndexError:
    obj = None
```

Comment: Hello, it is no my question. i say "I need something like Entry.objects.all()[::5], but I don’t know how to do this with my code."